# cast text from tableview with 2 sections to second view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am having trouble fixing casting the current week to a secondviewcontroller. I have my code like this:

My array:

```
var EUW = [("Week 1", "4 matches", "EUW"), ("Week 2", "4 matches", "EUW")]
var NA = [("Week 3" ,"4 matches", "NA"), ("Week 4", "4 matches", "NA")]
```

and my code like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   var secondscene = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    if let indexPath = MyTable.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
        let (currentweek,amountofmatches) = EUW[indexPath.row]
        secondscene.match = currentweek
        }
```

Now this code is working for the first section which is obvious because i havent defined any sections. So when i create a label in the secondviewcontroller saying what week it has received it says on week 1 of the first section week 1, week 2 week 2 but in the second section (the NA part) it says when clicked on week 3 week 1 and when clicked on week 4 week 2

But when i try to define the second section like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   var secondscene = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
    if let indexPath = MyTable.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
       if indexPath.section == 0 { 
           let (currentweek,amountofmatches) = EUW[indexPath.row]
          } else { let (currentweek,amountofmatches) = NA[indexPath.row]
          }
        secondscene.match = currentweek
        }
```

then it says that currentweek is an unresolved identifier and it doesnt build the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem with scope. In the last set of code, you define `currentweek` inside the `if` statement, when you do:

```
let (currentweek,amountofmatches) = EUW[indexPath.row]
```

Therefore, the `currentweek` variable will not be accessible outside the `if` statement. To fix this, you could do something like:

```
   var (currentweek:String,amountofmatches:String);
   if indexPath.section == 0 { 
       (currentweek,amountofmatches) = EUW[indexPath.row]
   } else { 
       (currentweek,amountofmatches) = NA[indexPath.row]
   }
   secondscene.match = currentweek
```